# form event 'actioncomplete' not firing

Tags: javascript, forms, events, extjs, extjs3

I sign the form on the 3 events but the event 'actioncomplete' not fired. The other two events are executed, success callback is performed.

```
if(obj instanceof Ext.form.BasicForm){
    var before='beforeaction';
    var complete='actioncomplete';
    var error='actionfailed';
}
obj.addListener( before, 
        function(o,e) {
                    this.changeSysState(lang[msg_id].loading,'loading','load_N_'+this.load_id);
                    }, this);
obj.addListener( complete, 
        function(o,e) {
                    this.showStatus(lang[msg_id].complete,'complete','load_N_'+this.load_id);
obj.addListener( error, 
        function(o,e) {
                    this.changeSysState(lang[msg_id].error,'error','load_N_'+this.load_id);
                    }, this);
```

My form

```
var changePanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        labelWidth     : 132,
        layout         : 'form',
        border         : false,
        defaults:{allowBlank:false,width:165},
        url            : '/xstore/xstore_change_pass.php',
        items : [ /*some fields*/ ]
});
```

submit call

```
var form = changePanel.getForm();
form.submit({
              success: function(r,o) {
                  winPass.destroy();
              }
           });
```

Server returns

```
{"success":true}
```

Use ExtJs 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that response, `actioncomplete` should be fired. You should search for reasons why it isn't. I see some issues with your code that might causing this behaviour:

- you declared `before`, `complete`, `error` as local variables and you use them out of scope; this might be an issue; use that instead:

  ```
  if(obj instanceof Ext.form.BasicForm){
      var before='beforeaction';
      var complete='actioncomplete';
      var error='actionfailed';

      obj.addListener( before, function(o,e) {
          this.changeSysState(lang[msg_id].loading,'loading','load_N_'+this.load_id);
      }, this);
      obj.addListener( complete, function(o,e) {
          this.showStatus(lang[msg_id].complete,'complete','load_N_'+this.load_id);
      }, this);
      obj.addListener( error, function(o,e) {
          this.changeSysState(lang[msg_id].error,'error','load_N_'+this.load_id);
      }, this);
  }
  ```
- you destroy something in `success` callback; this `success` callback is fired before `actioncomplete`, so if it also destroys form it might be another issue

If neither of those help, check in developer tools for server response. There might be some error code returned which also might be the reason.

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A98FK/2/) where you can see the second problem (`actioncomplete` not firing after destroying form).

Comment: Yes indeed the problem was the fact that I deleted the form before the  'actioncomlete' fired